# Expense of django query

Tags: mysql, django, django-templates

I have two tables: Actor and Images.  The Images table is linked to the Actor table through a Foreign Key.  I might make a query on Actor that pulls a list of all the actors with first name beginning with the letter A.  Let's say I store this query result in actor_list and pass it to the template.  I can get a list of all the Images through the template by iterating.  Something like:

```
{% for actor in actor_list %}
    {% for image in actor.img_set %}
       {{ image }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Is this costly to the database?  Does the associated img_set come through with the initial actor object list, or does a new query hit the database every time I call for the actor.img_set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should install the [Django debug toolbar](http://www.packtpub.com/article/django-debug-toolbar) and see what SQL queries are happening under the covers.

If you are getting too many queries, you can try using select_related() to pull in the related data in the initial query.

Comment: Agree with the debug-toolbar recommendation, but `select_related()` won't help in the case of a reverse relation, which this appears to be.

Comment: @ed: In addition to Daniel's comment and your last question: If it's a reverse relation the database will be hit for every actor to get his image set...

Comment: Thanks for input.  Follow-up question.  After checking the SQL from the Django Debug Toolbar, I see that the database is getting hit for even this: {{ actor_list.0.id }}.  Why does a SQL query go out when actor_list has already been created?  But no additional query is created if I iterate through the actor_list and pull the id that way

Answer (score 0):

Better than using the django toolbar is using the connections library.  With Debug set to True:

```
>>> from django.db import connection
>>> for actor in actor_list:
>>>  for image in actor.img_set:
>>>   image
>>> connection.queries()
```

This will show all the queries that were executed and the amount of time that each took.

The debug toolbar is cool, though, for many uses.  :-)